# How to transform a sequence of collection operations into a diff?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

I'm looking for an algorithm that can transform a sequence of collection  operations into a diff where operations can be: insertion, deletion and move.

For example:

```
I(0), I(0) -> I(0), I(1)
D(0), D(0) -> D(0), D(1)
M(1,0), D(0) -> D(1)
I(0), I(2), D(0) -> I(1)
I(0), I(0), I(0), M(0,5) -> I(0), I(1), I(5)
```

On the left side is the ordered sequence of operations to be applied on the collection, while on the right is the diff description of how collection is changed by the operations.

Order of diff operations is not important. Diff is a list of changes that happened, e.g. elements at indices 0 and 1 of the starting collection are removed, elements are inserted at indices 4 and 5 of the final collection, element is moved from index 3 of the starting collection to index 9 of the final collection, etc.

Note that two operations can annihilate each other or be transformed into one operation.

What I have so far in an algorithm that can merge two succeeding operations into a diff by doing a switch on all possible combinations and offsetting indices or transforming operations, but I'm not sure how to scale that on more than two operations as incoming operation affects all previous ones and can be annihilated in the process.

Comment: Are you sure the order of operations in your diff isn't important?  I(1),D(0) and D(0),I(1) are different if I understand your notion of diff correctly.  The first maps 1,2 -> new,2  while the second maps 1,2 -> 2,new